# How to convert datetime into time and select record from two diffent columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert date time into 24 hr time in sql server and i want to select the records based on time...!

my table is follows

```
id        1                     2                 3
starttime 12:00:00.0000000   01:00:00.0000000 12:00:00.0000000
EndTime   23:59:59.0000000   13:59:59.0000000 23:59:59.0000000
```

when  `startTime : 14/10/2013 01:02 AM and end time 14/10/2013 11:02 PM.` it should be display record **id 2 & 3**
my sql query is follows

```
SELECT * FROM  TableTimes 
WHERE StartTime >= CONVERT(char(8),CONVERT(time,'14/10/2013 01:02 AM',103), 108) 
AND [EndTime]<= CONVERT(char(8),CONVERT(time,'14/10/2013 11:02 PM',103), 108)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
SELECT * FROM  TableTimes 
HAVING StartTime >= CONVERT(char(8),CONVERT(time,'14/10/2013 01:02 AM',103), 108) 
AND [EndTime]<= CONVERT(char(8),CONVERT(time,'14/10/2013 11:02 PM',103), 108)
```

Comment: When you convert '14/10/2013 01:02 AM' into data type Time date is eliminated, DO you not want to take date into consideration ???

Comment: I just want to get records by using start & end time..!